# How to download git ignored folders and files from github

Tags: github, node-modules

Am trying to download node_modules from github inorder to install it in an offline machine,
What i did was just froked a repository and deleted the .gitignore file and tried  downoad the zip file again,but still not getting node modules

Is it possible to download ignored folders from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `node_modules` folder, as it is ignored, is not even saved in git. There's nothing you can do to download it with the rest of the repository, just run `npm install` or `yarn`. As the machine in question isn't connected, you'll naturally have to do this on an internet-connected machine.